# Явное лучше, чем неявное

Tags: python

В «Дзен Питона» есть вот такая строчка

- Явное лучше, чем неявное.

Но при этом в Python постоянно опускаются круглые скобки

Чтобы создать кортеж, нужно обязательно поставить запятую

```
a = (100,)
print(type(a)) #tupple
```

Но если не поставить запятую будет создаваться что угодно но не кортеж

```
a = (100)
print(type(a)) #int
a = ("str")
print(type(a)) #string
a = ([1,2,3])
print(type(a)) #list

# и т.д.
```

Можно даже сделать так

```
(a) = (100)
print(type(a)) # int
```

Из за опускания круглых скобок мне не сразу был понятен этот пример

```
rec = (0,1),(1,0)
(x1,y1),(x2,y2) = rec
```

Опускание круглых скобок разве не приводит к неявности? Они как бы и есть, но их как бы и нет.

Comment: В выражении есть запятая, вроде бы это достаточно явно указывает на создание кортежа

Comment: неявнось возникает при опускании запятой, а не скобки. для кортежа запятая = характерный признак, если неявно не указан другой тип данных.

Comment: И еще. не tupple, а tuple, произносится "тапл", если по-английски. А по-русски это "кортеж" называется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rec = (0,1),(1,0)
(x1,y1),(x2,y2) = rec
```

Скорее этот пример не про скобки и кортежи, а про **упаковку** и **распаковку** переменных. В данном случае скобки вообще не нужны, если вы дальше не собираетесь использовать переменную `rec` как-то отдельно:

```
rec = 0,1,1,0
x1,y1,x2,y2 = rec
```

Тот же самый код с тем же самым результатом. Просто есть правило, что переменные, перечисленные через запятую, упаковываются в кортеж. А распаковка может идти из кортежей, списков, итераторов (причём, возможны вложения) - не важно из чего, главное, чтобы можно было взять оттуда нужное число элементов.

Скорее, в вашем примере наоборот **добавлены лишние скобки**, чтобы сгруппировать вместе значения координат `x,y` просто по смыслу. Если бы речь шла только о получении результата, скобки были бы вообще не нужны.